# How does node handle sync and async code using the event loop?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Does node run through the js file and execute all synchronous code once before spinning up the event loop to handle all things asynchronously? Or is the synchronous part of the code handled as a callback in the event loop itself?

Comment: Yes and yes. The event loop is only executed when there are no other javascript code to execute. That means all synchronous code gets executed and at the end of everything node.js enters the event loop. All code in all callbacks are synchronous (I'm ignoring async/await for now you can think of the code after await as a callback). Callbacks gets called by the event loop. That means no callback gets executed when node first execute the synchronous code. When the event loop runs it waits for events and call the related function to handle the event - we call this mechanism "callback"

Comment: Note: By no callback I mean no asynchronous callback. You can of course write code that calls a callback synchronously. Examples of such functions are Array.forEach, Array.sort etc.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot.